# AMP Page - Hamburger icon rendering as “X” on a few mobile phones, Specifically Xiaomi Mobile Phones

Tags: android, html, css, amp-html, hamburger-menu

This is related to AMP - Accelerated Mobile Pages - responsive menu - Hamburger Icon.

The three horizontal lines of the hamburger icon render as "X" on a few mobile phones. In other mobile phones and desktop the hamburger icon renders correctly as three horizontal lines. To be more specific it is on all XIAOMI mobile phones on all browsers.

I am forced to insert an ugly text "Menu" in the code.

The CSS in the Head has the following script (s):

```
<script async custom-element="amp-sidebar" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-sidebar-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
```

And The Body has the following :

```
<header class="headerbar"><div role="button" on="tap:sidebar1.toggle" tabindex="0" class="hamburger">?Menu</div><div class="site-name">ABCD</div></header>[enter image description here][1]
```

Snapshot is also uploaded if allowed, I have a low credit rating of 1 . . .

Comment: Have you tried other icons?

Comment: Sounds like an icon or font issue. What's the CSS you're using to display the hamburger menu?

Comment: .hamburger {
 padding-left: 10px;
 float: left;
}